# JAVA - not working code

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, arraylist

I have first list_session which contains 1,2,2,3 .Second list_time contains 30,17,25,46 .When second element of list_session is equals with first element, then add this time to third list_time else add value=-1 .The same for third element and fourth etc.
My code not working. Why ?
How can I modify the code ?

```
while (it8.hasNext()) {
        tempTime = it8.next();
        tempSession = it7.next();

        if (testSession.equals(tempSession)) {
            testSession = tempSession;
            time.add(tempTime);
        } else {
            time.add(value);
            testSession = tempSession;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < time.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(time.get(j) + " time");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean, it's not working?  Throws an Exception?  Displays the wrong results?

Comment: You really don't show enough code. Please show at least how `list_session` and `list_time` are related to this fragment. Where do you plan to add value `-1`?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819) at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791) at appidentifysession.AppIdentifySession.main(AppIdentifySession.java:36) Java Result: 1      AppIdentifySession.java:36 is line which contains tempTime = it8.next();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, If you have some Association you have to use [Association List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list) in Java is Map,

Secondly, create map where key is session ID and value list of times

Thirdly, go through map and just check 2 and more values in Values list, with some condition you want.

P.S. Do not use TWO lists instead of an Association List it makes a lot of  mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Per the [ArrayList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

"The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future."

if it8 is an iterator on the list 'time', that's probably the culprit.  You are adding values directly to time, making the iterator it8 stale.  If you must add values in this way, you should use the iterator's add method instead.  Probably a better way would be to collect results in a different list entirely.